# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Configuration for Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, pipeline

I have added the Personal Access Token to Jenkins System configures, and the test result seems right.(it shows "**Credentials verified for user xxx**") but when adding new item and configure the gitlab project, **there is only an empty list for projects.**. I have tried both username/password or username/ssh-key. Many Thanks for any help!
[image]